# maps.googleapis.com script doesn't load in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, api

I've implemented Google Maps address autofill on my website and it works great in every browser except Internet Explorer; if I try to open the Maps [API script](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.35.exp&libraries=places&key=xxxxmykeyxxxxx) separately in a new tab, it takes forever to load (it loads fine in Chrome).

- I've tried reinstalling IE, adding `maps.googleapis.com` to trusted sites, checked firewall settings, and combed through most of the google results regarding this issue without any luck

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: How vital is it to support something which is already dead in the water & completely EOL by next year?

Comment: Internet Explorer has not been supported for ~3+ years, has only received a handful of security updates during that period _(it;'s literally been abandoned by Microsoft, which stated so in 2017ish)_, and no one should be using it, so supporting it generally wouldn't be a concern. _(**no one should be using any version of Internet Explorer**, as no version is secure; if needing IE for an ancient software platform that only works in IE, use [IE Tab](https://www.ietab.net/) which emulates IE in a Chromium-based browser - it's free and a license is only needing if wishing to customize)_

Comment: Windows 10 (and so Edge) is more than 5 years old. So at this point, every website, router and like device / app / site that I use now works fine with Chromium Edge. You need to make your website work with Chromium Edge.

Comment: Unfortunately a company that I work for uses IE for at least a few more months. That's why it's important to me. I understand your comments though.

Comment: Let's hope they don't use it for Microsoft Teams, as that will cease to work by the end of the month, & Office365 by next August.